# What win64 calls require alignment?

Tags: winapi, porting, win64

I was trying to figure out a port bug from win32 to win64 where a LB_GETSELITEMS message was returning a -1 in the 64 bit port, but not in the original 32 bit environment.

My head about exploded when I finally realized that the LB_GETSELITEMS requires that the lParam cannot be 2 byte aligned, but must be 8 byte (maybe 4 byte?) aligned.

I've not seen this documented anywhere.  Does anyone know of any documentation related to this?  Are there any other places where this is a problem?

Comment: Hmm, no, that's not documented anywhere.  Sounds pretty unlikely, but then it is also very unlikely to ever have a buffer that's not aligned to 8 in a 64-bit process.

Comment: That's hard to believe. I'd recommend writing a primitive Win32 app with a listbox and then trying to send LB_GETSELITEMS with buffers of various alignment: just get a big buffer `x` from `GlobalAlloc()` (it returns 8-byte aligned memory) and pass `x`, `x+1`, `x+2` etc.

Comment: Why did you have a 2-byte aligned buffer?  You must be doing something unusual.  If your unusual code also assumes that the WPARAM (which is the buffer's item count) is four bytes you could well be passing a bogus value which would cause this failure.  Perhaps you could paste some code.

Comment: @arx [LB_GETSELITEMS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): WPARAM is a number, so alignment isn't an issue.  LPARAM is a pointer, so alignment can be an issue.  Also, I'm not calling this directly.  I'm using a MFC wrapper.

Comment: @Adrian I know alignment isn't an issue for the WPARAM but, as I said, the size of a WPARAM could be an issue.  If you were reading the number out of a buffer then the increase in size from 4 to 8 bytes could have given you a bogus item count.  Why would you do that?  I've no idea, but I've no idea how you got an unaligned buffer either because you still haven't explained.  As I said before, you're plainly doing something unusual and if you told us what then maybe someone could answer your question.

Comment: @Joker_vD have run a test, and confirmed, it requires alignment under a 64bit build but not a 32bit build. ![sample image](http://i.imgur.com/dAcV6QB.png).

Comment: @arx Not sure what you mean.  That WPARAM becomes 8 bytes?  Then it would be a potential problem with signed numbers, as they wouldn't be sign extended. (WPARAM is a UINT_PTR) which would cause issues for -ve numbers.  As for why it is aligned to 2 bytes, in a word, legacy.  This application is 20 years old.  More research needs to be done to see what will break if we go to default alignment.

Comment: Weird. Wrote a small, pure WinAPI test program, works like a charm.

Comment: @Joker_vD Interesting, I'm actually not using pure WinAPI, I'm using MFC. Thought that MFC was mostly just an interface. If you're interested in the solution I created, you can dl it here.  Could you make available the solution you created?  Thanks.